# How to Update Streamlit AgGrid?

Tags: javascript, python, ag-grid, streamlit

I want to update the Streamlit AgGrid by adding an empty line when an external button is pressed. But instead of adding a row, a completely different grid is created with empty row. I would be very happy if you tell me where I am wrong or how I can fix it.

The codes are as below:

```
st.header("This is AG Grid Table")

df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
gd= GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gd.configure_pagination(enabled=True)
gd.configure_default_column(groupable=True)

gridOptions = gd.build()
grid_table = AgGrid(df,
                    gridOptions=gridOptions,
                    fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
                    height=500,
                    width='100%',
                    theme="streamlit",
                    update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED,
                    reload_data=True,
                    allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
                    )

button = st.sidebar.button("Add New Line")

if button:
    data = [['', '', 0]]
    df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CollaboratorName', 'Location', "HourlyRate"])
    df = pd.concat([df, df_empty], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    gd= GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
    gridOptions = gd.build()

    grid_table = AgGrid(df,
                        gridOptions=gridOptions,
                        #enable_enterprise_modules=True,
                        fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
                        height=500,
                        width='100%',
                        theme="streamlit",
                        update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED,
                        reload_data=False,
                        allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
                        )
```

When I run the program, the result is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcnV5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is wrong

```
df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column1', 'Column2', "Column3"])
```

Use this.

```
df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CollaboratorName', 'Location', "HourlyRate"])
```

Your program always execute 'df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')' from the top. So your add new line is useless when streamlit runs the code from top to bottom.

The trick is to save your new add line to csv.

Example.

```
if button:
    data = [['', '', 0]]
    df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CollaboratorName', 'Location', "HourlyRate"])
    df = pd.concat([df, df_empty], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

When streamlit runs the code from top to bottom again, your new line will be shown because it is already saved in csv.

So the change is only this.

```
button = st.sidebar.button("Add New Line")

if button:
    data = [['', '', 0]]
    df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CollaboratorName', 'Location', "HourlyRate"])
    df = pd.concat([df, df_empty], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Where can I do csv update after filling blank lines from the app. Could you help? @ferdy

Comment: On the `grid_table = AgGrid()` the `grid_table` contains the updated info. You can save it to csv. print the `grid_table` so you will see its structure and type.

Comment: When I do update_mode=GridUpdateMode.GRID_CHANGED, my writing disappears from the cell when I press enter. I saw the grid before my edit.

When I do update_mode=GridUpdateMode.NO_UPDATE, the changes I made on the grid are not lost from app, but this time I can't update csv at all :(

Comment: Post another issue with title for example, how to save the aggrid output to csv file. Then post some code where you failed to save/update it. I will attempt to solve it. Others can of course.

Comment: I did. May you visit link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73436687/how-to-edit-cell-of-streamlit-aggrids-row