# How to Edit Cell of Streamlit AgGrid's Row?

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

I have already created `AgGrid` by loading data from a csv file. I am adding rows one by one via an external button. But when I try to edit the line I added, it disappears. I would be very grateful if you could help me where the error is. The codes are as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridUpdateMode,  JsCode
from st_aggrid.grid_options_builder import GridOptionsBuilder
import sys
import os
import altair as alt
from streamlit.runtime.legacy_caching import caching

def data_upload():
    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    return df

if 'grid' in st.session_state:
    grid_table = st.session_state['grid']
    df = pd.DataFrame(grid_table['data'])
    df.to_csv(“data.csv”, index=False)
else:
    df = data_upload()

gd = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gd.configure_column("Location", editable=True)
gd.configure_column("HourlyRate", editable=True)
gd.configure_column("CollaboratorName", editable=True)

gridOptions = gd.build()


button = st.sidebar.button("Add Line")

if "button_state" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.button_state = False

if button or st.session_state.button_state:
    st.session_state.button_state = True
    data = [['', '', 0]]
    df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CollaboratorName', 'Location', "HourlyRate"])
    df = pd.concat([df, df_empty], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv(“data.csv”, index=False)
    gd= GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)


grid_table = AgGrid(df,
                    gridOptions=gridOptions,
                    fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
                    height=500,
                    width='100%',
                    theme="streamlit",
                    key= 'unique',
                    update_mode=GridUpdateMode.GRID_CHANGED,
                    reload_data=True,
                    allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
                    editable=True
                    )
if 'grid' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['grid'] = grid_table
else:
    grid_table_df = pd.DataFrame(grid_table['data'])
    grid_table_df.to_csv(“data.csv”, index=False)
```

You can see the running app from here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdleb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one has a different approach but the goal could be the same.

Two radio buttons are created, if value is `yes` new line will be created, if value is `no` there is no new line.

If you want to add a new line, select yes and then add your entry. Then **press the update button** in the sidebar.

[image]

If you want to edit but not add a new line, select `no`, edit existing entry and then **press the update button**.

### Code

```
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridOptionsBuilder
import pandas as pd


def data_upload():
    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    return df


def show_grid(newline):
    st.header("This is AG Grid Table")
    df = data_upload()

    if newline == 'yes':
        data = [['', '', 0]]
        df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CollaboratorName', 'Location', "HourlyRate"])
        df = pd.concat([df, df_empty], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

    gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
    gb.configure_default_column(editable=True)
    grid_table = AgGrid(
        df,
        height=400,
        gridOptions=gb.build(),
        fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
        allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
    )
    return grid_table


def update(grid_table):
    grid_table_df = pd.DataFrame(grid_table['data'])
    grid_table_df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)


# start
addline = st.sidebar.radio('Add New Line', options=['yes', 'no'], index=1, horizontal=True)
grid_table = show_grid(addline)
st.sidebar.button("Update", on_click=update, args=[grid_table])
```

Answer (score 0):

That happened because of your `if button:` statement. Streamlit button has no callbacks so any user entry under a `st.button()` will always reload the page so you end up losing the data, to prevent this, you can either initialize a `session state` fo your button or you can use `st.checkbox()` in place of `st.button()`.

In this case I am going to fix your code by initializing a **session state** of the button.

```py
def data_upload():
    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    return df

st.header("This is AG Grid Table")
if 'grid' in st.session_state:
    grid_table = st.session_state['grid']
    df = pd.DataFrame(grid_table['data'])
    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)

else:
    df = data_upload()

gd = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gd.configure_column("Location", editable=True)
gd.configure_column("HourlyRate", editable=True)
gd.configure_column("CollaboratorName", editable=True)

gridOptions = gd.build()

def update():
    caching.clear_cache()

button = st.sidebar.button("Add Line")       

# Initialized session states                 # New code     
if "button_state" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.button_state = False

if button or st.session_state.button_state:
    st.session_state.button_state = True            # End of new code
    
    data = [['', '', 0]]
    df_empty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CollaboratorName', 'Location', "HourlyRate"])
    df = pd.concat([df, df_empty], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    gd= GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
    gridOptions = gd.build()

grid_table = AgGrid(df,
                    gridOptions=gridOptions,
                    fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
                    height=500,
                    width='100%',
                    theme="streamlit",
                    key= 'unique',
                    update_mode=GridUpdateMode.GRID_CHANGED,
                    reload_data=True,
                    allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
                    editable=True
                    )
if 'grid' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['grid'] = grid_table

grid_table_df = pd.DataFrame(grid_table['data'])
grid_table_df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

I think your code should work fine now with regards to the button issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I learned. But I still have a same problem after your change.